# Disabinge woocommerce variable product price doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried several codes to disable the price in product variable in woocommerce.

I've tried this but nothing happened:

```
/*
Disable Variable Product Price Range completely:
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html','my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );

function my_remove_variation_price( $price ) {
$price = '';
return $price;
}
```

I put it in functions.php but nothing happened.

My theme is saha from theme-junkie.

Comment: You wrote 2 parameters, but your function contains just one, edit it. I think it will help: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html/

Comment: You can safely change it to **1** instead of **2** as all you want to do is remove `price` and this hook will be called only on variable products. But there are caveats, 1) `woocommerce_variable_price_html` hook was introduced on v3.0.2  so it won't work on previous versions, 2) you should be checking if you're on a frontend page related to **display of products**.

Answer (score -1):

Best way would be to hook into `woocommerce_get_price_html` `filter`.

It passes `$price` HTML and `WC_Product*` object. You can check if it is `instance of WC_Product_Variable` to determine if it is a variable product. Then just return `''` empty string if it is. This will handle the price display for parent Variable product.

#### Example

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mm_handle_variation_prices', 10, 2);
function mm_handle_variation_prices( $price_html, $product_obj ){
    // Bail unless we are on WooCommerce page on frontend and this is an ajax request.
    if( is_admin() || is_ajax() || ! is_woocommerce() ) {
        return $price_html;
    }

    // If this is an Variable product only then return empty string.
    // '$product_obj instanceof WC_Product_Variable' check would work as well.
    if( 'variable' === $product_obj->get_tyepe() ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $price_html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why would this answer be down voted that too without any comments? This function works flawlessly on all Woocommerce versions with full backward compatibility while `woocommerce_variable_price_html` hook was added in v3.0.2 thus it is not backward compatible.